# How many comparisons does it take to find a number in a grid of numbers arranged in an $N \times N$ square

Tags: algorithms, induction

We have an $N \times N$ squares, filled with integer numbers monotonically increasing in "right" and "down" directions.

So from any point, if you move left the number will get bigger, or if you go one step downwards the number would get bigger.

Using induction (preferably) prove we need $2N-1$ comparisons at most, to find out if a given number is in the square or not.

Each comparison will let us know if the number in the square is bigger, smaller or equal to the number we seek.

Comment: Interesting question. I'd tend to hope this can be done in log time but surprisingly the nasty way the square is ordered might not allow it after all.

Comment: @DRF: You can't get below $\Omega(N)$: suppose all the entries before the codiagonal are $0$ and all the entries after the codiagonal are $2$ -- then the elements on the codiagonal doesn't tell you anything about each other and you have to inspect all of them to find out if there's an $1$ somewhere.

Comment: @henningmakholm You are assuming nondecreasing instead of increasing. I'm not sure if you can adapt your argument to that though. My feeling came from the fact that searching in ordered arrays can be done in $\log(n)$ though that might not carry over.

Comment: @DRF: Yes, I didn't notice that, but the argument is the same: Suppose all element in the NW triangle are $\le 0$ and all elements in the SE triangle are $\ge 3$. Then you need to look at the entire antidiagonal before you can be sure there isn't any $1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh I think I see what you are saying. Pretty much the antidiagonal is totally unordered. You could have any arbitrary order relation on it which is realizable with a smart choice of numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Essentially this matrix continued downwards in the obvious fashion $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&\cdots&n-1&n-1+\epsilon_1\\2&3&\cdots&n-1&n-1+\epsilon_2&n\\3&\cdots&n-1&n-1+\epsilon_3&n&n+1 \end{bmatrix}$ Gah why the last 3 doesn't get aligned properly is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitive Algorithm assuming matrix is completely monotonic:

1. Search along diagonal starting from (1,1).

1 worst case: exactly N comparisons

2. number will be between two kitty corner numbers on the diagonal (i,i) and (i+1, i+1). So, start from (i,i+1) and search moving right until you hit (i,N) or you find what you're looking for.
3. start from (i+1,1) and move right until you hit (i+1,i). If you find what you're looking for, you're done. Otherwise, your number isn't on the list.

2/3 Worst case: N-1 comparisons

Therefore, total, 2N-1 comparisons.

If you need to use induction, your base case is a 1X1 matrix - trivial. Then, for the inductive step, inside an N+1 X N+1 matrix, there is an NXN matrix that is also doubly monotonic. Implication follows. Constructive proofs are better than inductive in my opinion.

For the general case, I'll have to work that out.

Comment: I don't understand "kitty corner". How would your algorithm find the 1 in $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1&2&2\\0&0&0&2&2&2\\ 0&0&0&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: Hmm I think I'm confused what about the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 &5 &15\\5& 10& 25\\11& 17&30\end{bmatrix}$ and the number 15. I stop between $(2,2)$ ,$(3,3)$ searching right from $(2,3)$ doesn't get me 15 and neither does searching from $(3,1)$

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think the matrix must be strictly increasing along rows and columns but you could easily fix that in your matrix by using a couple more numbers I think.

Comment: @DRF: Yes, but I only noticed that after it was too late to edit the comment.

Comment: Mis read the original question, my bad. I thought the matrix was completely monotonic, which would make $a_{ij}$ > $a_{i+1,j-1}$ I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: I dont get the inductive approach. I know the base case, but how do you do the inductive step?